# How could create a crosstab SQL query with Django ORM?

Tags: sql, django, orm

Using Django 1.1, how could I create a crosstab (pivot table) SQL query using the ORM?

UPDATED:
These are the models and output requirements:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Order(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, blank=True, null=True, related_name='orders')
    description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)       
    type_detail = models.CharField(_('Type Detail'), max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(_("Cost"), max_digits=14, decimal_places=2)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(_('modified'), auto_now=True)
```

Currently the view is showing data like so:

```
Store   | Type Detail  | Quantity 
----------------------------------
Walmart | Floor polish | 2        
Walmart | Tiles        | 1        
Walmart | Milk         | 4      
Another | Floor polish | 2        
Another | Tiles        | 1        
Another | Milk         | 4
```

I want to pivot this to view the data like so:

For a store I need to know quantities

```
Store   | Floor polish  | Tiles | Milk
------------------------------------------------
Walmart | 2             | 1     | 4
Another | 2             | 1     | 4
```

I hope that explains what I need.

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more detail. What models do you have, and what results do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in the template as follows (assuming you are passing line_items to your template and also assuming store.name is a unique property):

```
{% regroup line_items by store.name as store_items %}
{% for store in store_items %}    
  <tr>
    <td>{{ store.grouper }}</td>
    {% for item in store.list %}
      <td>{{ item.count }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This would work if all stores have the same inventory, otherwise you'll need to fill the gaps in the view (returning 0's for missing inventory items, for example)

Answer (score 2):

A proper crosstab requires a value for each dimension member. Here's something I made up (see below). You could use this in a Django template like in the doctext example. So you'd issue queries for 1) all Store values, 2) all type_detail values and 3) quantity per store and type_detail. The result of the third query then into a dictionary of (store, type) => quantity.

```python
class Cube(object):
    """Iterable sparse cube. Iterating gives an item for every dimension member.

    >>> pythons = ['eric', 'john', 'terry']
    >>> cheeses = ['limburg', 'feta', 'parmigiano']
    >>> cheese_consumption = {
        ('eric', 'limburg'): 2,
        ('eric', 'parmigiano'): 4,
        ('john', 'feta'): 5
    }
    >>> cheese_cube = Cube((pythons, cheeses), cheese_consumption)
    >>> for python, python_cheeses in cheese_cube:
        for cheese, consumption in python_cheeses:
            print python, cheese, consumption or 0

    eric limburg 2
    eric feta 0
    eric parmigiano 4
    john limburg 0
    john feta 5 
    john parmigiano 0
    terry limburg 0
    terry feta 0
    terry parmigiano 0
    """
    def __init__(self, dimensions, facts, slice=None):
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.data_dict = facts
        self.slice = slice or ()
    def __iter__(self):
        if len(self.slice) + 1 < len(self.dimensions):
            for item in self.dimensions[len(self.slice)]:
                yield item, Cube(self.dimensions, self.data_dict, self.slice + (item,))
        else:
            for item in self.dimensions[len(self.slice)]:
                yield item, self.data_dict.get(self.slice + (item,), None)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about Django, but here's plain SQL

```
SELECT Store,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type_Detail = 'Floor polish' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as 'Floor polish',
SUM(CASE WHEN Type_Detail = 'Tiles' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as 'Tiles',
SUM(CASE WHEN Type_Detail = 'Milk' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) as 'Milk'
FROM Order
GROUP BY Store
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have hard-coded the columns into the SQL, so if a new type is added, you have to change the SQL.